# Need a Font Selector for Winforms ToolStrip

Tags: winforms, toolstripbutton

I can quickly create a list of the installed Fonts (Takes a long time to load the fonts into the TabStripDropDownButton by the way), but I would rather have a ToolStrip button that shows the FontDialog.  Anyone know of a opensource or commerical control or sample that does this?  I havent been able to find anything.

Comment: I think you don't need exact new staff, just put StripToolbar (or something similar) put button on on and put a code that open FontDialog in that button that's it.

Comment: You are right I over thought this. So simply put a button on the TabStrip and used the FontDialog from there.

Answer (score 1):

Recommending a software library is off-topic, but to just show the built-in font provider, you can just use the FontDialog class:

```
using (FontDialog fd = new FontDialog()) {
  if (fd.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK) {
    textBox1.Font = fd.Font;
  }
}
```

The windows FontDialog form won't win any design awards.

You can also consider caching the font list after it's created the first time and just load that on subsequent openings.

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking what I was trying to accomplish. So as was suggested I just used the FontDialog from a button on the ToolStrip. Sorry about wasting peoples time.